# Drools Stateless Kie Session returning stale value from Global Variables

Tags: drools, rule-engine

We have a use case where we need two consecutive drools rule evaluations, where we are creating new StatelessKieSession every time including new container instance, we are storing the result in a global variable within StatelessKieSession, result object is created for both executions. Sometimes the result that we are reading from global variable in second execution is returning the value from first execution. What could be behind this?

Comment: Can you include an example in code of what you're doing and how you're interacting with this global? I'm a little confused about if you're trying to use a global as a surrogate for the working memory and trying to access it in the 'when' clause, or something else.